# Mysql many many- tables and queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a major brain fart on this problem and im hoping someone can take a  look at this and give some clues on how to do this.

I have 4 tables - users, book_copies, library locations, book.

```
Create table book 
( id int not null auto incre, 
  name varchar(55), 
primary key(id) );

Create table book_copies 
( id int not null auto incre, 
  number of copies), 
primary key(id) );

Create table location 
( id int not null auto incre, 
  address varchar(55), 
primary key(id) );

Create table users 
( id int not null auto incre, 
  name varchar(55), 
primary key(id) );
```

i have a many many relationship between book_copies and locations, bookcopies and users, book and book copies with adding the many-many table

```
Create book_copies_locations 
( locationid int (11) not null, 
  bookcopyid int (11) not null, 
primary key(locationid,bookecopyid) , 
foreign key (locationid) references locations.id, 
foreign key (bookcopyid) references book_copies.id) );

Create table borrow 
( userid int (11) not null, 
  bookcopyid int (11) not null, 
  checkoutdate varchar(55), 
  duedate varchar(55), 
primary key(userid,bookecopyid) , 
foreign key (userid) references users.id, 
foreign key (bookcopyid) references book_copies.id) );

Create table book_copies_books 
( booksid int (11) not null, 
  bookcopyid int (11) not null, 
  checkoutdate varchar(55), 
  duedate varchar(55), 
primary key(booksid,bookecopyid) , 
foreign key (booksid) references books.id, 
foreign key (bookcopyid) references book_copies.id) );
```

What i want to do is track copies of every book, and tell what locations it is at?, and what user checked it out?, and what date?

i added something like

```
insert into borrow (userid,bookcopyid, checkoutdate, duedate) values( '1', '1', 'dec 18', 'jan 11')

insert into users (id,name) values( '1', 'bob')

insert into book_copies (id,number_of_copies) values( '2', '33')

insert into books (id,name) values( '1', 'harry potter')

insert into locations (id,address) values( '1', 'health science public library')
```

how would i make the query to return that there are 2 copies of harry potter, checked out on dec 18 and due on jan 11, and located at health science public library?

Am i setting up the tables right with the many to many tables? is there another way i should be doing this?

Comment: Aside from the main question I don't think that the schema design is that bad. I'd recommend that you store the `book_copies` data differently though and store one entry per copy. The table would look something like (id, book_id, copy_id) or (id, book_id)

Comment: In addition to what James said, I also suggest that you store the dates as `DATE` types; when you get lots of records, the tables will be much smaller and the indexing much more efficient.

Comment: The `book_copies_locations` has a problem, too. A bookcopy can be in several locations with this setup. You should add a `UNIQUE (bookcopid)` constraint to that table.

Comment: Also: you don't store if (and when) a book is returned.

Comment: @ypercube I guess he deletes the `borrow` row when it's returned.

Comment: @Barmar: In thAt case, he needs a `UNIQUE (bookcopid)` constrAint in table `Borrow` as well (so there is no possibility of a book borrowed twice).

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather see your schema like this:

```
book (id, name)
book_copy (id, location_id, book_id, status)
```

Note that, to count the copies of a given book, you look in book_copy.  In your example, there would be two rows for book_id = 1.

`status` would be a denormalized value, to keep you from having to determine the latest status from the checkout history.

Users then checkout a copy of the book:

```
book_checkout (id, user_id, book_copy_id, checkout_date, due_date)
```

Add in your `user` and `location` tables, and you should be all set.

As others have pointed out, get your UNIQUE indexes setup well.